# Question about factory Constructor sample in Dart docs

Tags: dart

The following is the factory constructor example in the Dart docs.

```dart
class Logger {
  final String name;
  bool mute = false;

  // _cache is library-private, thanks to
  // the _ in front of its name.
  static final Map<String, Logger> _cache = <String, Logger>{};

  factory Logger(String name) {
    return _cache.putIfAbsent(name, () => Logger._internal(name));
  }

  factory Logger.fromJson(Map<String, Object> json) {
    return Logger(json['name'].toString());
  }

  Logger._internal(this.name);

  void log(String msg) {
    if (!mute) print(msg);
  }
}
```

does the implementation to `factory Logger.fromJson` call the cache checking factory constructor `factory Logger(String name)` or the private constructor `Logger._internal(this.name)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It calls the first factory constructor you have defined in your example. If you want it to call the constructor `Logger._internal`, you need to call it explicit like:

```dart
  factory Logger.fromJson(Map<String, Object> json) {
    return Logger._internal(json['name'].toString());
  }
```

When in doubt, you can in both Intellij and VSCode hold Ctrl down and click on the constructor/method you call and it should navigate you to the called constructor/method.

Intellij does also highlight the called constructor/method if you put your text cursor on the constructor/method:
[image]